# Flutter: Scroll, move widget, everything in the same screen

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to implement the following screen in Flutter.

[image]

It seems trivial to do so, but I couldn't find a way to achieve the same results. This is what I have so far:

1. My solution without scrolling

[image]

2. Solution following the [Flutter demo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/contacts_demo.dart) but placing a map as a `SliderAppBar`
   [image]

As you can see, I have a few problems:

1. This is the most accurate solution (don't look at the small blue widget moving up and down). I can move on the map and scroll through the `ListView` but I can't move the divider to expand the `ListView`. Notice that I don't want the `ListView` to move to the top, but until the user stops.
2. This one seems the correct solution but, as you can see, there are more problems: The map seems to resize instead of stay the same but just resize its container, and when I scroll down, I see the background of the `Scafold`.

Any ideas? This is the [link](https://pastebin.com/NFdGxXL9) to the solution 1.

PD: Sorry for the links to the GIFs. Their size was about 10MB each and I couldn't upload here.